# how to check whether the string ends with exact string?

Tags: java, string

The input is XYZ

The String array contains three string
i.e.

1. test.alpha.beta.XYZWorld
2. test.gamaa.mu.XYZ
3. test.nu.tera.XYZ

I need the last two result if i provide the input "XYZ". Not the test.alpha.beta.XYZWorld.
if i use lastIndexOf method defined in java.lang.String, obviously it returns 1,2 and 3 result.

Please help.

Comment: Have you looked at the `endsWith(String suffix)` [method in String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) ?

Comment: Your lastIndexOf has to be exactly the length of your input smaller than the length of your test string. In the case of test.alpha.beta.XYZWorld, it will be less than that.

Comment: Thanks.. never heard this method... My Bad.... it works..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `endsWith()` method in `String`.

Comment: can we do this?:first change toCharArray say a[]

    if(a[i]=='X'&&a[i+1]=='y'&&a[i=2]=='z'&&a[i+3]=='\0'){
    //end string 
    }

Comment: You can do that, but it is ugly.

Comment: yeah endsWith() is better :)

Answer (score 2):

check out [**String.endsWith(suffix)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method from **String API**. it returns a **boolean value**.

```
  String s = "test.gamaa.mu.XYZ";
  System.out.println(s.endsWith("XYZ"));

  returns TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    String pattern = "xyz";
    String a = "xyz";
    String b = "xyzA";

    int position = b.lastIndexOf(pattern);
    if (b.length() == position + pattern.length())
    {
       System.out.print("OK");
    } else
    {
        //error
    }
```